# Semi-partial correlation and interaction

Tags: regression, correlation, partial-correlation

I am evaluating some customer satisfaction data, and want to calculate how much each predictor variable contributes to the response (customer satisfaction). Ideally, I would use the Shapley Value Regression method, but that is unavailable on SPSS. I tried using semi-partial correlation, but the values are inaccurate because interaction between predictors variables exists. 
Any idea how I can perform my desired calculations accurately?

Comment: The semi-partial correlation isn't inaccurate because of interaction (correlation) between predictors variables, it controls for this correlation and statistically removes the effect of the conditional "predictors"; i.e. provides the correlation estimate between the "response" and "predictor" of interest while controlling for the rest.  What is it that you expect/want?

Comment: @Patrick Wouldn't multicollinearity yield invalid results? I want the percent contribution of each predictor variable on the response. What would make a semi-partial correlation inaccurate?

Comment: Let me ask it this way, if there was no multicollinearity, would partials be required?  If there was no multicollinearity, wouldn't partial correlations be equivalent to standard correlation estimates? I am trying to stimulate a discussion of your question; I know we are all taught that multicollinearity is an issue when estimating regression coefficients, but I do not think (please correct me if I am wrong) this is an issue when calculating partial or semi-partial correlation estimates. I do think they are biased statistics and therefore "inaccurate" re: estimating true population values.

Comment: @Patrick So you think it shouldn't matter? I have results from a Shapley Value Regression test, and they are not matching semi-partial correlation values I get. That's what I don't understand...